# How to change Deeplens Online Time

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-deeplens

I am using aws deeplens to deploy the object detection models. I could see that my device is going to offline after 15 minutes and again I am restarting to bring it to online. It is annoying me while I am giving demo to my clients. Can anyone help me, how to increase the deeplens online time from 15mins to 2 hrs atleast. I couldn't found any useful info from aws documentation aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research I found that, if you have issues with your deeplens then reset it and register again. Then it will be working fine.